# Cloudant data encryption

Tags: database, encryption, nosql, cloudant

I have a question about cloudant and data encryption, I’m doing a project, I don't know if I can encrypt the data in cloudant, I did an investigation but I did not find something in particular, someone here knows something about this topic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cloundant’s disks are encrypted at rest, and data in flight over https. Data in the database itself during normal operation isn’t encrypted—although it’s perfectly feasible for you to do so in the client. Note, however, if you encrypted the data client-side, Cloundant cannot index your data.

Answer (score 0):

in addition to xpqz's answer, this blog shows how to do client side transformation of Cloudant data for additional encryption outside of "at-rest" and "in-motion"

https://blog.cloudant.com/2018/10/10/Client-Side-Transformation.html